Observe file opening and closing on macOS
I would like to watch a file for openening and closing. I already tried different ways like kqueue or FSEventStreamCreate. Unfortunately, none of this showed, if the file was closed.
Is this even possible and if so, how can I do it in Swift?
EDIT
I also found solutions about using lsof. This really shows me, if the file is opened or closed, but I would need to use a timer to call lsof as often as possible to find out, wheter the file is opened or closed. So I think this is not a good solution.
EDIT 2
As asked, here is the example how I use FSEventStream:
class FileWatcher {
    private var fileURLs: [URL]
    private var stream: FSEventStreamRef?
    
    init(fileURLs: [URL]) {
        self.fileURLs = fileURLs
    }
    
    deinit {
        stopWatching()
    }
    
    func startWatching() {
        let paths = fileURLs.map { $0.path() } as CFArray
        let callback: FSEventStreamCallback = { _, _, _, eventPaths, _, _ in
            print(eventPaths.load(as: Int32.self))
        }
        
        var context = FSEventStreamContext(version: 0, info: nil, retain: nil, release: nil, copyDescription: nil)

        stream = FSEventStreamCreate(nil, callback, &context, paths, FSEventStreamEventId(kFSEventStreamEventIdSinceNow), 1, FSEventStreamCreateFlags(kFSEventStreamCreateFlagFileEvents))
        FSEventStreamSetDispatchQueue(stream!, DispatchQueue.init(label: "watching"))
        FSEventStreamStart(stream!)
    }
    
    func stopWatching() {
        if let stream = stream {
            FSEventStreamStop(stream)
            FSEventStreamInvalidate(stream)
            FSEventStreamRelease(stream)
            self.stream = nil
        }
    }
}



What have you tried so far?

As I told: kqueue, FSEventStreamCreate and lsof

You should provide a minimal example console app (which is possible) where you demonstrate how you call function FSEventStreamCreate  with which parameters - and what you expect and what the outcome is.

I fear, you need to observe the processes for opening and closing files. File System events or DispatchSource events may observe events on the file level, but  these don't have options to observe a file when it gets opened or closed. lsof would be a viable tool for this.

@CouchDeveloper: Somehow it must be possible without using lsof. Unfortunately I don't understand the code so far: https://github.com/apple-opensource/lsof/tree/master/lsof

I found this link: https://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2010/May/msg01455.html
Translated to Swift I have this function:
func pidsAccessingPath(_ path: String) -> [Int32] {
    var result: [Int32] = []
    
    let pathFileSystemRepresentation = FileManager.default.fileSystemRepresentation(withPath: path)
    
    var pidsSize = 0
    var pids: UnsafeMutablePointer<pid_t>?
    
    let listpidspathResult = proc_listpidspath(UInt32(PROC_ALL_PIDS), 0, pathFileSystemRepresentation, UInt32(PROC_LISTPIDSPATH_EXCLUDE_EVTONLY), nil, 0)
    
    guard listpidspathResult >= 0 else {
        return []
    }
    
    pidsSize = Int(listpidspathResult > 0 ? listpidspathResult : 1)
    pids = UnsafeMutablePointer<pid_t>.allocate(capacity: pidsSize)
    
    guard let pidsPointer = pids else {
        return []
    }
    
    let secondListpidspathResult = proc_listpidspath(UInt32(PROC_ALL_PIDS), 0, pathFileSystemRepresentation, UInt32(PROC_LISTPIDSPATH_EXCLUDE_EVTONLY), pidsPointer, Int32(pidsSize))

    guard secondListpidspathResult >= 0 else {
        pids?.deallocate()
        return []
    }
    
    let pidsCount = Int(secondListpidspathResult) / MemoryLayout<pid_t>.size
    
    for i in 0..<Int(pidsCount) {
        result.append(pidsPointer[i])
    }
    
    pids?.deallocate()
    
    return result
}

It seems to work so far, I get the process ids, who access this specific file. Unfortunately there are two disadvantages:

I need to use a timer to check as often as possible if the file still is open.

Somehow it sometimes needs a long time to realize, if the file is closed or not. So after closing, the function still gives back the process id of the application, altough the file was closed. But it seems, that lsof has sometimes the same issue.


UPDATE
I tried this method in a timer with 1 second. Only checking one file causes a CPU use of 15 % on a M2. This seems not to be a good solution so far, so any other ideas are welcome.
